# Making object field optional and adding a block to resource definition only if the field has been set

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I have following problem:

We have a module responsible for creating an Azure Event Hubs namespace along with multiple event hubs. The list of event hubs is represented as a list of objects. I want to expand this module with support for Azure Event Hubs Data Capture, however this needs to be present only for some event hubs. I started with adding a `capture_description` field to the appropriate variable definition of the modules variables definition like here:

```
variable "event_hubs" {
  description = "List of Event Hubs that will live in the namespace."
  type = list(object({
    name                = string
    message_retention   = number
    partition_count     = number
    consumer_groups     = list(string)
    capture_description = object({
        enabled             = bool
        encoding            = string
        interval_in_seconds = number
        size_limit_in_bytes = number
        skip_empty_archives = bool
        destination         = object({
            name                = string
            archive_name_format = string
            blob_container_name = string
            storage_account_id  = string
        })
    })
  }))
  default = []
}
```

The problem is that I want the `capture_description` to be optional so it can be unset for some elements of the list. Then, in `main.tf` there is a foreach loop creating a resource for each element of the list from `variables.tf`. I came up with a following solutioon based on "dynamic" block and foreach loop that should have 0 or 1 iterations depending on whether the `capture_description` has been set. It look like this:

```
# Create the Event Hub(s)
resource "azurerm_eventhub" "ehub" {
  for_each = local.event_hubs

  name                = each.value.name
  partition_count     = each.value.partition_count
  message_retention   = each.value.message_retention
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.namespace.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.namespace.resource_group_name

  dynamic "capture_description" {
    for_each = each.capture_description == null ? [] : list(var.capture_description)

    content {
        enabled = capture_description.enabled
        encoding = capture_description.encoding
        interval_in_seconds = capture_description.interval_in_seconds
        size_limit_in_bytes = capture_description.size_limit_in_bytes
        skip_empty_archives = capture_description.skip_empty_archives
        destination         = {
            name                = capture_description.destination.name
            archive_name_format = capture_description.destination.archive_name_format
            blob_container_name = capture_description.destination.blob_container_name
            storage_account_id  = capture_description.destination.storage_account_id
        }    
    }
  }
}
```

However I have serious doubts whether it's going to work as expected. Are you able to evaluate my proposed solution and suggests something that has a non-zero chance of working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fair point. The answer is that I have no environment to play around and Azure costs money so I cannot set up one for myself or I would rather like to avoid it. I need to come up with something that has a chance of being at least a bit more than a piece of crap code. Also - this module is responsible for numerous existing event hubs. If I f it up It will have a huge impact on the entire enteprise infra.

Comment: I'm guessing as a first step you can run `terraform plan` right? That should show you if the code is working or not.

Comment: No. The plan has to be created for an existing infrastructure, I have no infra to build the plan for.

Comment: Well, running `terraform plan` for what you have coded will show you at first is it running or not.

Comment: Is it possible to init terraform with no resource provider and no underlying infra?

Comment: Yes, init only downloads the binaries you need. Plan will not create anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare an attribute of an object type constraint as being optional you can use the `optional` modifier.

```
variable "event_hubs" {
  description = "List of Event Hubs that will live in the namespace."
  type = list(object({
    name                = string
    message_retention   = number
    partition_count     = number
    consumer_groups     = list(string)
    capture_description = optional(object({
        enabled             = bool
        encoding            = string
        interval_in_seconds = number
        size_limit_in_bytes = number
        skip_empty_archives = bool
        destination         = object({
            name                = string
            archive_name_format = string
            blob_container_name = string
            storage_account_id  = string
        })
    }))
  }))
  default = []
}
```

The `optional` modifier means that when converting an object that doesn't have that attribute Terraform will automatically insert that attribute with the default value `null`.

You can use that fact in a `dynamic` block by using the splat operator `[*]` to concisely convert the value from a single value that might be null into a list with either zero or one elements:

```
  dynamic "capture_description" {
    for_each = each.capture_description[*]

    content {
      # ...
    }
  }
```

The `[*]` operator will produce `[]` (empty sequence) if its operand is `null`, or a single-element sequence containing the operand if the operand is not null. Therefore you can use `capture_description.value` inside the `content` block to refer to the `capture_description` object passed in by the caller.

Comment: +1000000 - this is what I needed and it solves my problem. Your'e the boss!